# Base Mesh changes back to its original form after switching to object mode

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-groups, inverse-kinematics

I downloaded the free RoyalSkies Male Rig from his website just to play around. I made the character less buffed up with proportional editing but it reverts back to its original form after switching back to object mode. How do I fix this issue?  [image: In edit mode]

[image: In object Mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your object has shapekeys, you have a shapekey selected and therefore you're changing this shapekey, you're not changing the original shape, which is on the top of your list and which is called *Basis*. If you want to make any change to the original shape, select this shapekey called *Basis*. If you want to save the shape you've created and make it the basis mesh, go into the dropdown menu on the right (down arrow) and select *Move to Top*. To make any shapekey appear in *Object* mode you need to tweak the *Value*, under the shapekey list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Its working perfectly now